# Accessing Steam client via C#

Tags: c#, .net, steam

Is it possible to access some Buttons of the Steam Client via C# .NET?
Basically, I want to automate some tasks (without writing a bot of any kind) in the Steam Client.

Now, is there any way on how to access the Buttons and Textfields and labels and such in the Steam Client itself directly?

So basically, press the button "Library" if a button is pressed on my form?

**EDIT:**
Just to make sure, I don't want any web-APIs, I am just talking about the actual client.

Comment: *"I want to automate some tasks (without writing a bot of any kind)"* a program to automate tasks is kind of the definition of a bot.

Comment: I should clarify that, not really automate, but simplify...

Answer (score 1):

You could use the CodedUI test framework available in Visual Studio - it has all the code neccessary for driving either a web or a Windows client application. I realise you are not trying to write a test program - but the libraries CodedUI uses have all the neccessary classes to achieve what you are attempting.

Comment: Wouldn't work sadly. Afaik, CodedUI is only available in the Enterprise edition of VS2015